# How do I seal ice cream containers?

Tags: ice-cream

I want to make ice cream, put them into pint containers (or, hopefully of any custom size in the future) and have the containers be sealed with a film like Häagen-Dazs does.

A machine would be ok. Manual would be fine too. I just want to know where to get the equipment and/or some instructions. Thank you.

Comment: There probably are machines for this, and I hope that somebody will answer about them. But why do you want it in the first place? If you simply want an airtight seal to prevent freezer burn, plastic containers with a "no leak" gasket are the most convenient option. A "no tamper" seal is rarely needed at home.

Comment: I usually just use plastic wrap pressed right on the surface of the ice cream to prevent freezer burn, but I'm unsure if you want / need more than that.

Comment: Consider just a regular [vacuum sealer](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=vacuum+sealer) if "tamper evident" is important. If the ice cream is already frozen, you don't need a [chamber sealer](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=vacuum+sealer+chamber&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Avacuum+sealer+chamber) which can get extremely expensive.

Comment: Are you talking about the rings around the outside of the carton or film that seals between the top of the carton and the product?

Comment: I was referring to the latter.

Answer (score -1):

Go to sunbeltpackaging.com and look under "options for lids".  It's a company I found on the internet while looking for "how do I seal ice cream containers with plastic film".  There are many choices there.

Comment: Thank you. I looked through some of their products, but couldn't find anything specifically for lid sealing.